# Apexcharts show all tooltip when page loads without hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, apexcharts

I copied samples from Apexcharts demo javascript and I want to show all the tooltips right after page loads.

```
var options = {
      series: [{
      name: "sales",
      data: [{
        x: '2019/01/01',
        y: 400
      }, {
        x: '2019/04/01',
        y: 430
      }, {
        x: '2019/07/01',
        y: 448
      }, {
        x: '2019/10/01',
        y: 470
      }, {
        x: '2020/01/01',
        y: 540
      }, {
        x: '2020/04/01',
        y: 580
      }, {
        x: '2020/07/01',
        y: 690
      }, {
        x: '2020/10/01',
        y: 690
      }]
    }],
      chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 380
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
        formatter: function(val) {
          return "Q" + dayjs(val).quarter()
        }
      },
      group: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '10px',
          fontWeight: 700
        },
        groups: [
          { title: '2019', cols: 4 },
          { title: '2020', cols: 4 }
        ]
      }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Grouped Labels on the X-axis',
    },
    tooltip: {
      x: {
        formatter: function(val) {
          return "Q" + dayjs(val).quarter() + " " + dayjs(val).format("YYYY")
        }  
      }
    },
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
```

I tried below but it only shows one tooltip and disappears when I hover on to the chart. I want it to show all right after page loads so that I can use it to print using browsershot

```
$('.apexcharts-tooltip').css({ opacity: 1 });
$('.apexcharts-tooltip').show();
```

Comment: Showing all tooltips is rather uncommon, certainly not supported by apexcharts; it might be possible with  some complicated hacks, but before trying something like that I'd like to recommend  using [datalabels](https://apexcharts.com/docs/datalabels/) - they are quite configurable, they have their own `formatter` and might look nicer than the heavy tooltips. Have you tried those?